# How to use jwplayer API in javascript

Tags: jwplayer

I'm having trouble of how to implement the jwplayer API or library into my javascript file. I'm trying to run the following command

```
jwplayer().setCurrentCaptions(1);
```

But  I'm getting the following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (content.js:45)
```

I know its because i haven't like explicitly defined jwplayer. jwplayer is supposed to be the object given by the API but I don't know how to make that available to my file? How do I define `jwplayer`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the player script in your HTML page. Somewhere before you run the `jwplayer().setCurrentCaptions(1)` method.

Should look like this:

`<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/YOUR-PLAYER-ID.js"></script>`